# ASP.NET MVC4 - Using a model to create a new record in 2 separate MySQL tables

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller, "Hardware" which has a "Create" action.

The model looks like:

```
namespace Inventory.Models
{
public class HardwareModel
    {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string UPDATED { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Brand")]
    public string BRAND { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public string MODEL { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works just fine in conjunction with the /Hardware/Create/ controller which was generated (create action uses Razor template), however, when a new item is created, I would like to also update another table which keeps track of which item was updated (ID from HardwareModel), and when it was updated.  I am able to get both of these fields I need - but my question is, how do I extend this model to create a new record in 2 seperate tables? (using MVC4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a candidate method for a service layer.

If your business logic dictates that creating a HardwareModel entity also requires creating two other entities, enforce that rule in a service method and unit test that the create methods for those two entities are called.

Comment: Thanks Kurt.  The service layer worked just fine for my purposes, and in fact, I am glad it was not possible to use 2 models - utilizing this service layer kept the code clean and simple.